# How to put image logo on the leftmost part of the Nav bar?

Tags: javascript, html, css, navbar

I am currently creating a navigation bar for a test webpage and I am having trouble aligning the logo of the website which is an image. I am a beginner in CSS so can someone give me some tips on how to arrange the logo.

P.S. This code is not yet finished so don't mind the list part just the logo part

Thanks!!

```js
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>Header Footer — Kayelah Sews</title>
        <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/a076d05399.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <div id="logo"><img src="Logo.jpg" alt="Logo"></a>
                </div>
                <div class ="items">
                    <li><a href="home.jsp">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="collections.jsp">Collections</a></li>
                    <li><a href="aboutMe.jsp">About Me</a></li>
                    
                </div>
                <li class="search-icon">
                    <input type ="search" placeholder="Search Products">
                    <span class="fas fa-search"></span>
                </li>    
                <li><a href="account.jsp">Account</a></li>
                <li><a href="cart.jsp">Cart</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </body>

 <style>
    @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Playfair+Display&display=swap');
    @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Open+Sans:wght@300&display=swap');
     
     *{
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        color: black;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
     }
     
     #logo{
        flex-basis: 20%;
        font-size: 0;
     }
     #logo img{
        height: auto;
        width: auto;
        max-height: 40%;
        max-width: 40%;
        overflow: hidden;
     }
     nav{
        background: white;
        padding: 10px 40px 10px 70px;
        border: 1px solid #B0B1AE;
        border-left: none;
        border-right: none;
        
     }
     nav ul{
         display: flex;
         list-style: wrap;
         align-items: center;
         justify-content: center;
     }
    
     
 </style>
    
</html>
```

Comment: You shouldn't have `<div>` inside `<ul>`

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way. You have to change two CSS properties on `nav` and `nav ul`.

After change `nav`:

```
 nav{
    background: white;
    padding: 10px 40px 10px 0;
    border: 1px solid #B0B1AE;
    border-left: none;
    border-right: none;
 }
```

Here left padding was covering 70px from the left on you code. I make it 0.

and `nav ul`:

```
nav ul{
     display: flex;
     list-style: wrap;
     align-items: center;
 }
```

Removed `justify-content` to put the element in left most position.

Answer (score 0):

I removed `justify-content: center;` in your `nav div` css selector so your image can actually be on the right. Or you could use a `position: absolute;`.

Here is the final code:

```css
*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  color: black;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

nav{
  background: white;
  padding: 10px 40px 10px 70px;
  border: 1px solid #B0B1AE;
  border-left: none;
  border-right: none;

}
nav ul{
   display: flex;
   list-style: wrap;
   align-items: center;
   /*justify-content: center;*/
}

#logo{
  flex-basis: 20%;
  font-size: 0;
}
#logo img{
  height: auto;
  width: auto;
  max-width: 40%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <div id="logo">
                <img src="https://placekitten.com/200/300" alt="Logo">
            </div>
            <div class ="items">
                <li><a href="home.jsp">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="collections.jsp">Collections</a></li>
                <li><a href="aboutMe.jsp">About Me</a></li>

            </div>
            <li class="search-icon">
                <input type ="search" placeholder="Search Products">
                <span class="fas fa-search"></span>
            </li>    
            <li><a href="account.jsp">Account</a></li>
            <li><a href="cart.jsp">Cart</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</body>
```

Comment: Where is the `<ul>`?

Comment: Remove it so that its horizontally aligned. let me add it again